# Time Series Data: Resample.mean() causing missing values

Tags: python

I have time series data which gives values every second, I am sampling this data in 5 minute intervals therefore I have aggregated by the mean for every 5 minutes. However,  when I use resample.mean() I receive some missing values and I was wondering why that is?

Thank you for your help!

```
            Time                                A      B           C    
7908    2021-07-12 00:00:00.035812792+00:00 0.74900 1000000.0   0.74905
7909    2021-07-12 00:00:00.050670938+00:00 0.74900 1000000.0   0.74905
7910    2021-07-12 00:00:00.065535015+00:00 0.74900 1000000.0   0.74905
7911    2021-07-12 00:00:00.120588579+00:00 0.74900 2000000.0   0.74905
7912    2021-07-12 00:00:00.125803018+00:00 0.74900 4000000.0   0.74905

PrimaryBookD.isnull().sum()

Time 0
A    0
B    0
C    0

PrimaryBookF= PrimaryBookD.resample('5T', on='Time').mean()
PrimaryBookG=PrimaryBookF.reset_index()

PrimaryBookG

Time                               A           B               C
0   2021-07-12 00:00:00+00:00   0.748834    3.781859e+06    0.748884
1   2021-07-12 00:05:00+00:00   0.748536    3.987342e+06    0.748586
2   2021-07-12 00:10:00+00:00   0.748677    3.725352e+06    0.748727
3   2021-07-12 00:15:00+00:00   0.748540    3.777257e+06    0.748590
4   2021-07-12 00:20:00+00:00   0.748233    4.366575e+06    0.748284

PrimaryBookG.isnull().sum()

Time   
A    2952
B    2952
C    2952
```

Missing values

```
is_NaN =PrimaryBookF.isnull()
row_has_NaN = is_NaN.any(axis=1)
rows_with_NaN = PrimaryBookF[row_has_NaN]
print(rows_with_NaN)
```

```
                                   A    B             C              D
Time                                                                      
2021-07-26 17:00:00+00:00        NaN         NaN        NaN         NaN   
2021-07-26 17:05:00+00:00        NaN         NaN        NaN         NaN   
2021-07-26 17:10:00+00:00        NaN         NaN        NaN         NaN   
2021-07-26 17:15:00+00:00        NaN         NaN        NaN         NaN   
2021-07-26 17:20:00+00:00        NaN         NaN        NaN         NaN   
...                              ...         ...        ...         ...   
2021-08-09 07:35:00+00:00        NaN         NaN        NaN         NaN   
2021-08-09 07:40:00+00:00        NaN         NaN        NaN         NaN   
2021-08-09 07:45:00+00:00        NaN         NaN        NaN         NaN   
2021-08-09 07:50:00+00:00        NaN         NaN        NaN           
2021-08-09 07:55:00+00:00        NaN         NaN        NaN
```

Output shape of this line

```
PrimaryBookZ=PrimaryBookF.reset_index()
PrimaryBookZ.loc[(PrimaryBookZ['Time']>pd.to_datetime('2021-07-26 17:00:00+00:00')) &(PrimaryBookZ['Time']<pd.to_datetime('2021-07-26 17:20:00+00:00'))].shape

(3, 11)
```

Comment: can you show some example ?, hope you have used rolling mean

Comment: How do you input a rolling mean when resampling?

Comment: excuse on that, i had view of movie average in taking samples, Can you stress some missing value places , couldn't figure out any

Comment: Thanks Kiran for your help, I have displayed the na values lmk if you need anymore data. Perhaps I have done something wrong earlier is it normal for NAs to be created after averaging?

Comment: unless if the resample windows doesnt have any single time stamp, it wont show any null values @Emmanuelle, would you ensure for the missing window data is there

Comment: would you share output shape of this line `df.loc[(df['Time']>pd.to_datetime('2021-07-26 17:00:00+00:00')) &(df['Time']<pd.to_datetime('2021-07-26 17:20:00+00:00'))].shape`